# Next JS npm start app load 404 page not found error for physical pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, npm-start

My project works well with ***run dev*** command but when I try to ***npm start*** I got 404 page not found error for other pages (*pages/...*) except Index.js.

I tried several ways which I found from forms(gthub issues, and blogs), but nothing worked.

Any Idea? Actually why there should be difference between run dev and start? I think we should see whats wrong in our app during the dev process

the scripts from package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next",
  "start": "next start",
  "build": "next build"
```

},

and next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
  }});
```

As you see I didn't change anything after installing nextJS.

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have server side file? what web framework do u use?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is next js app. The site is working well with npm run dev

Comment: please provide more code, so we can understand your situation, like your `app.js` or server files that listen to browser's request

Comment: @DarrylRN, I didn't change anything which is comming with nextjs. There is not any app.js or other things. Just installed app, added few pages. in npm run dev everything working well, but with npm start, all routing pages return 404 page not found. I am in LOCAL, not publishing anything yet, just would like to see localhost:3000 as production.

Comment: can you check file's name? Convert camelCase to lower case and try again))

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71841110/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54815348/11107541

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that if the filenames have uppercase letters on Windows, you get a 404 error.

I changed all filenames to lowercase characters and the 404 errors went away.

Comment: Hi Guarav. Yes as mentioned in comments, it is related with latter cases

Comment: this also happens in MacOS :V

Comment: anyone know the reason for this? is it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that has this issue, make sure your basePath in `next.config.js` is correct. If you've messed with the base path as I did, your routing will break and you'll see a 404 on every page.

Comment: Thank you very much, only this answer helped me, idk why is it underestimated

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand what kind of app do you want to build.
Is it serverless? or kind of with server and what web server do u want to use (there are so many options).

**For serverless app:**

All you need to do for production build is `next export`, this function will generate static files to be served as your website. [Read more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/amp-support/amp-in-static-html-export)...

**For app with server:**

If you want to run `npm run start`, you need to do `npm run build` first.

`npm run build` compiles and optimizes your build for production mode.

`npm run start` run your web server to serve your html files.

If you have done those two steps, it means something wrong with your server files, your web server's API didn't listen to the request, therefore it doesn't redirect you to the correct page.

Comment: I am in local, I didn't start to puplish it to any server. Just would like to start app to see what will be result in production. I am adding console screenshots to questions.

Comment: I did everything in local. Just installed nextjs app, worked with run dev,, now start app in npm start.. and the result is nothing is working.

Comment: please provide the example of your page code, I found the example works fine in my local with production build `npm run build && npm run start`

Comment: Ok, I am adding few more screens.

Comment: Could you please let me know which pages exactly you want to see?

Comment: my suggestion is to add custom server to serve your pages, you can take a look on the example here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-express, there are other options as well to be used like hapi, koa, etc. The reason is bcs your pages structure has become complicated and I'm not sure how to handle that with default next-router.

Comment: I did everything like you mentioned. But the result is the same. for npm start all pages return 404 not found except index.js

Comment: How do you handle your requests in app.js / server file?

Comment: Possible  no one will believe me, but problem was solved after I change signIn to signin (lower letters) (((( I don't know what is the problem with upper letters exactly. But I lost a week for this bug((( Thank you for your responses. and times

Comment: glad to hear that, no worries, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Before starting your application you need to build using npm run build command and then start your application.

Comment: Of course I am building it before starting, I didn't mentined it in question because it is the first step. I built the app, then npm start and website opens normal, but can not navigate between pages,, all pages is like 404 page not found.