# A 404 error occurs when refreshing an app using next-i18next

Tags: next.js, page-refresh

I'm making a multilingual service using next-i18next, but there seems to be an error related to routing

Git Repository: https://github.com/fatherslable/test-repo

problem situation

1. If you connect to localhost:3000 and press refresh, there is no problem.
2. There is no problem even if you connect to localhost:3000/test and press refresh.
3. If you connect to localhost:3000/en and press refresh, there is no problem.
4. If you connect to localhost:3000/en/test and press refresh, a 404 error occurs.

It seems that my next app cannot find the page if I refresh it while the language of another country such as en is applied instead of ko.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The repo is down, and I suppose that I am late to the party, but in case anyone else encounters something similar double check your `next.config.js`. It can be that some config is missing (for example [sub-path-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing) might be missing `locales`, the language from `locales` or `defaultLocale`).

Also make sure you are not using any routing from React ( more details [here about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71841110/getting-404-page-not-found-nextjs))

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. When I restart the backend server whenever I deploy a newly built code on the server, the problem goes away.