# Nextjs 404 error on reload/ refresh action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I'm using Nextjs for a front-end application and dotnet core 3.1 for the Web API. There are some pages that are static and other that are dynamic I followed the official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) to achieve this. On development mode (local machine) everything works fine. Both static and dynamic routes are working properly and fetching data from the dontnet core Web API.

However, when publishing the Nextjs app following this steps:

1. yarn build
2. yarn export
3. An out folder is generated at the root of the project
4. The content of that folder is uploaded to the server

After, the deployed files are uploaded and when loging to the app, it redirects to the main page (until here is working OK), but as soon as I click on the reload page botton (Chrome) I am gettint the 404 error.

[image]

Looking at the console in the developer tools I got this:
[image]

I found this Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815348/nextjs-page-goes-to-404-on-refresh) with same issue but there the answer is to use Express for server routing. In my case I am using dotnet core Web API for server requests. So, not sure how to do that.

Is there a way to fix this from the client side? Might be a configuration is missing?

The only thing I noticed while doing the export was a message saying: **No "exportPathMap" found**. Not sure if that would the the reason.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, few questions and consideration:
1. `"The content of that folder is uploaded to the server"` it is a static web hosting (S3, blob storage, etc) ?

2. The page `account.html` is inside the exported files? If so, if you open `http://yourpath/account.html` it opens the page?

3. `"After, the deployed files are uploaded and when loging to the app, it redirects to the main page (until here is working OK)"` I think is because you're doing full client side navigation (with push history from html) but once you reload the page the path `/account/` is not registered.

Comment: hi @Pierfrancesco, for questions #1 and #2, yes. We are using AWS S3 for hosting the site and the account.html is between them. Also, yes we are doing client validation. Do you know how can I register the /account/, so it can render after the reload?

Comment: hello again, this is something "homemade" but helped me for the same (I think) situation.
When you upload files on S3 (web site hosting enabled: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) try to remove `.html` in file extension for all files generated by export excepts for `index.html`. Then set `ContentType` to `text/html` for all the files you've removed the extension.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: how can you remove .html extension when exporting nextjs static blog?

Answer (score 20):

I had got similar issue in react when all of my pages after building and exporting had ".html" extensions. I solved it by the following code in **next.config.js** file.

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  exportTrailingSlash: true,
}
```

**Note**: Do not work with the above code while in development. Use it just before building the project.

You can find the documentation link here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap#adding-a-trailing-slash.

**UPDATE**

The above code was for next.js v**9.3.4** which I was using at that time. For newer versions below code should be used according to docs.

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful link. But maybe there is a typo or the configuration is changed lately. Currently the configuration is

module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}

Comment: Fix to 

module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}

And it does work in Dev as well, so please fix that too and I'll upvote :)

Comment: This just worked for me! What a weird setting to cause such an issue...

Answer (score 0):

it has been fixed update your nextjs package

```
 npm install next@latest
```

based on the current version of Next js you have, [visit here to see if there's any breaking change before updating what you have](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where after deploying the `out` folder created by `next export` all URL's would redirect me to the homepage. Everything was working fine during development and all URL's were accessible with `next/link` but in order to access pages with a URL I had to add a `.html` extension at the end of the URL.

Because I needed a quick workaround I added a useEffect block in the `_app.tsx` file for rerouting so that upon landing on the homepage it would act as if a Link component was clicked redirecting to the entered URL.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
        router.push(window.location.href)
    },[])
```