# Next.js 404 Issues

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js blog project. I have a page that is meant to render article content from a CMS. Querying the blog post data from the CMS works fine. The issue seems to be with Next.js specifically in that Next deems my page as non-existent.

Below is a snippet pages directory structure:

```
pages/
-------article/
--------------[slug].tsx
```

Previously the article page was rendering with no issues. For some unfathomable reason, Next returns a 404 when I navigate to this page.

Comment: What does the URL to the page look like? Can you add the code for that page to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is that page working fine when you navigate from home page via `<Link />` but will return 404 when you refresh page or visit directly to that page?

If yes, please check these:

[Nextjs 404 error on reload/ refresh action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208254/nextjs-404-error-on-reload-refresh-action)

[Nextjs page goes to 404 on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815348/nextjs-page-goes-to-404-on-refresh)

Comment: When navigating to the Page from any location within the application, it comes back as 404. The same is true when loading the page directly by pasting a url to it in the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the codebase