# Get "This page could not be found." on refresh page - using Next Js and React-admin

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-admin

**Context**
I currently have created a project using React-admin and NextJS.

**Problem**
Whenever I refresh the page I'm redirected to the *404 page* - It has started after I had removed the hash from the URL (localhost:3000/#/). It only works well when I'm at the localhost:3000 page.

**Code:**

```
// into src/admin/ReactAdmin.tsx file
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin'
import { createBrowserHistory as createHistory } from 'history'

const history = createHistory()

import {
  RestrictionList,
  RestrictionEdit,
  RestrictionCreate,
} from './components/restricao/'
import baseDataProvider from './DataProvider'

const App = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={baseDataProvider} history={history}>
    <Resource
      name='source'
      list={RestrictionList}
      edit={RestrictionEdit}
      create={RestrictionCreate}
    />
  </Admin>
)

export default App
```

---

```
//into next.config.js file
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

---

```
// into src/pages/index.tsx file
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const ReactAdmin = dynamic(() => import('../admin/ReactAdmin'), {
  ssr: false,
})

const HomePage = () => <ReactAdmin />

export default HomePage
```

Comment: Had similar issues, what version of nextjs are you using? [check this similar issue and possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208254/nextjs-404-error-on-reload-refresh-action)

Comment: HI @shammahk, thanks for sharing. I'm using "^12.0.8". This is the latest one.

Comment: Does the issue happen while in dev mode?

Comment: Exactly, @juliomalves. It's in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used ***next export*** in your build?
If yes, you need to add this config in your next.config.js:

```js
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:any*',
        destination: '/',
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `next export` does not support rewrites, though (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features). You wouldn't be able to use this with static HTML export. You may want to omit the reference to `next export` altogether from your answer.