# Can't access my pages by URL, only by links in next js

Tags: javascript, url, next.js

I have an application built with next JS. It works fine in development, but when published to the internet, I have a problem. The only way I can access the pages in the application are by the links on the home page, that link to those pages. For example, I get a 404 error if I type in [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about), but if I click the link that routes to it, everything is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs page goes to 404 on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815348/nextjs-page-goes-to-404-on-refresh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also having a similar problem.

Configuring the `trailingSlash` in next configuration worked for me.

In the root of your project in *next.config.js* try adding:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't comment because of my experience point. Could you share your code for higher components/pages? For now what I understand is your browser can't fetch the data before render, so you get an error. It' is a wild guess but maybe you can add a condition to your components(for example for url/about let's say you render about() component) that

```
if (!data){ return <div>Loading</div>}
```

This is an approach that I used at React apps(never used next) but since they are quite similar it might help you.

Comment: I found my problem, I needed to use the Link component from next/link so that next could "open" the link.

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for the update also. I'm sure I'll have to fix something similar in the future